# After adding jQuery plugin image positioning messed up?

Tags: jquery, image

After I added the jQuery plugin [Captify](http://thirdroute.com/projects/captify/) my image layout has messed up. What I'm aiming them to look like is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyi9U.png) but it ends up looking like [this](http://jakep.info/html5/) after adding the plugin. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance

Comment: That is one cute kitten!

Comment: thank placekitten for that :P

Comment: As to your question, without looking at the original markup. The DIV containing your image is not floated left. Which makes it go into 1 column

Comment: Ah I see, I just floated the div in question to the left and now it looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/04gyz.png). I guess that's because the css now only applies to the first image. Looks a lot closer to what I was expecting though thank you!

Comment: @Jake, yup you just need to apply a class and space it out a bit. You also have an errant `<br class='c'>` in there between each image which is adding to the confusion. Just need to remove that as well

Comment: @JohnP awesome, thanks man! It seems like the plugin was overriding the padding for the image, so I used margin instead to space out the images. Does this seem reasonable (plugin over-riding padding)?

Comment: @Jake, yeah some plugins add styles directly to element. I always prefer them adding a class and working with it rather than messing the styles. Easily fixed though. I'll add this as an answer then..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML the DIVs aren't being floated. Adding a class and floating/inlining the DIVs should solve your problem. You might also want to remove the `<br>` tag after each element because they would mess up the flow of your DIVs even if you floated them.